# How to require command line parameters in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I need to have some parameters. Usage should be **only** between:

```
./script.sh --scan [scan type] [keyword]
```

or

```
./script.sh --help
```

In example it should be something like this:

```
$ ./script.sh 
[Usage]
$ ./script.sh --scan
Specify scan type
$ ./script.sh --help --scan
[Usage]
$ ./script.sh --scan short
Specify keyword to search
$ ./script.sh --scan short keyword
[Starts short scanning for "keyword" - go to function where my script is, blah, blah]
$ ./script.sh keyword --scan short
[As above]
$ ./script.sh keyword
[Usage]
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: There's nothing built in, if that's what you're asking. You just have to write the code to do this validation.

Comment: I know, I'm just asking for this code because after two hours of trying I can't make it anyway :/

Comment: You'll want to use [`getopt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/getopt.1.html). I found a decent walkthrough [here](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt). Search on your system for a file named "getopt-parse.bash" for a complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed that! The basic version is:

```
#!/bin/bash
function usage
{
        echo "Usage: usage"
        exit
}
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        case $1 in
                -h|--help)
                        usage
                        ;;
                -s|--scan)
                        scantype="$2"
                        shift
                        ;;
                -*)
                        usage
                        ;;
                *)
                        keyword="$1"
                        ;;
        esac
        shift
done
if [ -z "$scantype" ]; then
        echo "no scantype"
        exit
fi
if [[ "$scantype" != "full" && "$scantype" != "long" && "$scantype" != "extended" && "$scantype" != "short" ]]; then
        echo "invalid scantype"
        exit
fi
if [ -z "$keyword" ]; then
        echo "nokeyword"
        exit
fi
echo "scantype: $scantype"
echo "keyword: $keyword"
```

Anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head:

```
if [ "$1" = "--scan" ] ; then
    if [ "$#" -ge 2 ] ; then
        _SCANTYPE=$2
        if [ "$#" -ge 3 ] ; then
            _KEYWORD=$3
        else
            echo -n "Specify keyword to search: "
            read _KEYWORD
        fi
    else
        echo -n "Specify scan type: "
        read _SCANTYPE
        echo -n "Specify keyword to search: "
        read _KEYWORD
    fi
    # Actual scan code
else
    # Display usage info
fi
```

This is pretty basic, of course, but hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but the beginning of your question said that the first command line parameter should only be "--scan" or "--help".  If it is anything besides "--scan", the usage message should be displayed.  If it is "--scan", then the scan type and the keyword should be provided, in that order.  Was that not what you intended?

Comment: @Bielecki : "The point is to don't mind the parameters order."  Darn, missed this before I wrote up my answer. How can a program know if it is 'scanType keyword' or 'keyword scanType'? ....... ALSO, traditionally items in a call list surrounded in `[...]` are optional, so it could also be `(nothing) OR keyword OR scanType` (besides the 2 I have listed previously). Is it really worth this much trouble? Life is short ;-)

Comment: @shellter: "items in a call list surrounded in [...] are optional" - yup, my bad. Program should know, because scantype is preceded by --scan and keyword is stand-alone.

@Leslie: try to enter to your script `./script (keyword) --scan (scantype)`. It will not work, because if first parameter isn't `--scan`, it will display usage.

Comment: @Bielecki : you wrote in your first comment "after two hours of trying I can't make it anyway" . Hmm. too bad you didn't include your failed code in you Q. we've wasted our time  on a rather unspecific specification. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Almost any `Configure` script to build a piece of software from source will have what you want.  From perl's:

```
: option parsing
while test $# -gt 0; do
    case "$1" in
    -d) shift; fastread=yes;;
    -e) shift; alldone=cont;;
    -f)
        shift
        cd ..
        if test -r "$1"; then
            config_sh="$1"
        else
            echo "$me: cannot read config file $1." >&2
            error=true
        fi
        cd UU
        shift;;
    --help|\
    -h) shift; error=true;;
    -r) shift; reuseval=true;;
    -s) shift; silent=true; realsilent=true;;
    -E) shift; alldone=exit;;
    -K) shift; knowitall=true;;
    -O) shift; override=true;;
    -S) shift; silent=true; extractsh=true;;
    -D)
        shift
        case "$1" in
        *=)
            echo "$me: use '-U symbol=', not '-D symbol='." >&2
            echo "$me: ignoring -D $1" >&2
            ;;
        *=*) echo "$1" | \
                sed -e "s/'/'\"'\"'/g" -e "s/=\(.*\)/='\1'/" >> optdef.sh;;
        *) echo "$1='define'" >> optdef.sh;;
        esac
        shift
        ;;
    -U)
        shift
        case "$1" in
        *=) echo "$1" >> optdef.sh;;
        *=*)
            echo "$me: use '-D symbol=val', not '-U symbol=val'." >&2
            echo "$me: ignoring -U $1" >&2
            ;;
        *) echo "$1='undef'" >> optdef.sh;;
        esac
        shift
        ;;
    -A)
        shift
        xxx=''
        yyy="$1"
        zzz=''
        uuu=undef
        case "$yyy" in
            *=*) zzz=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!=.*!!'`
                 case "$zzz" in
                 *:*) zzz='' ;;
                 *)   xxx=append
                      zzz=" "`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!^[^=]*=!!'`
                      yyy=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!=.*!!'` ;;
                 esac
                 ;;
            esac
            case "$xxx" in
            '')  case "$yyy" in
                 *:*) xxx=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!:.*!!'`
                      yyy=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!^[^:]*:!!'`
                      zzz=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!^[^=]*=!!'`
                      yyy=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!=.*!!'` ;;
                 *)   xxx=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!:.*!!'`
                      yyy=`echo "$yyy"|sed 's!^[^:]*:!!'` ;;
                 esac
                 ;;
            esac
        case "$xxx" in
        append)
        echo "$yyy=\"\${$yyy}$zzz\""    >> posthint.sh ;;
        clear)
        echo "$yyy=''"          >> posthint.sh ;;
        define)
            case "$zzz" in
        '') zzz=define ;;
        esac
        echo "$yyy='$zzz'"      >> posthint.sh ;;
        eval)
        echo "eval \"$yyy=$zzz\""   >> posthint.sh ;;
        prepend)
        echo "$yyy=\"$zzz\${$yyy}\""    >> posthint.sh ;;
        undef)
            case "$zzz" in
        '') zzz="$uuu" ;;
        esac
        echo "$yyy=$zzz"        >> posthint.sh ;;
            *)  echo "$me: unknown -A command '$xxx', ignoring -A $1" >&2 ;;
        esac
        shift
        ;;
    -V) echo "$me generated by metaconfig 3.5 PL0." >&2
        exit 0;;
    --) break;;
    -*) echo "$me: unknown option $1" >&2; shift; error=true;;
    *) break;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For your two examples

```
./script.sh --scan [scan type] [keyword]
```

or

```
./script.sh --help
```

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
usageMsg="usage:ScriptName --scan [scan type] [keyword] OR --help"

case $# in
  [123] ) : nothing_may_be_OK ;;
  0 ) # no args, display usageMsg
      echo "$usageMsg" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
esac

case "$1" in
  --[Hh][Ee][Ll][Pp] ) echo "$usageMsg" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
  --[Ss][Cc][Aa][Nn] )
      shift
      case $# in
        0) # using defaults 
           scanType="PrimaryScan" # change to your default scanType
           keyword="PrimaryKeyWord" # again, change to your default value
        ;;
        1) 
          echo "$usageMsg" >&2
          echo "must provide both [scan type] and [keyword] arguments. Cant continue" >&2 
          exit 1
        ;;
        2)
           scanType="$1"
           keyword="$2"
        ;;
      esac   # case $#
  ;;
esac          # case $1

#restof your code goes here
echo "running scanner with scanType=$scanType and keyWord=$keyword"
echo ". . . . ."
exit 0
```

I'm guessing that your usage pattern means `--scan` OR advanced scan (with details), i.e. `--scan [scan type] [keyword]`

If you really intend for user to optionally add `[scan type]` AND/OR `[keyword]` then you'll need some further use of the techniques in the code above.

IHTH